# HADOOP PIG output - how to skip JSON phase

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

Having my PIG's results, I have some time bags, some time tuple in my result structure. Sometimes bag are empty, sometime tuples are empty.

When I do a 'Flatten' on an empty bag I got some very strange error : like the name of the field appear, deleting the value associated to it.

I just would like PIG to output a simple csv, but when I do a PigStorage, it outputs all the curly braces, and tuple parenthesis that are resulting from the data structure. I don't know how to get out of that. Any clue ? I tried the "Dump" method, but it has been removed from the current pig version (I am in 0.14).

So, as of today, I do PigJson dump. And I have a python script that goes back reading the jsons created by Pig and recreating a nice tabular presentation of the data. I am guessing that it is not the way it is supposed to be done. How can we flatten data structure in pig when we don"t know it by advance ??

How do you do this in your daily programmer life ??

Comment: Dump still exists in pig 0.14.0. You can write your own storage function

Comment: Dump doesn't work on Grunt. I read it has been removed in Pig 0.7. How should I write my storage function ?

Comment: Can you post some sample outputs and expected outputs as well as schemas.

Comment: unfortunately I can't : I have no internet access from my working place :-(